# Pesquisa de Filtro

Tags: php, mysqli, algoritmo-de-busca, filtro

estou com um problema para criar um filtro de busca com select, fiquei bem confuso, vou postar o codigo e uma imagem do que necessito:

o codigo:

```
 <?php 
    session_start();
    include_once("../../conexao/conexao.php");
    include_once("../../seguranca.php");
    include_once("../../header.php");
    include_once("../../menu.php");
    seguranca_adm();
    ?>


    <?php
    //Verificar se está sendo passado na URL a página atual, senao é atribuido a pagina 
    $pagina = (isset($_GET['pagina']))? $_GET['pagina'] : 1;
    if(!isset($_GET['pesquisar'])){
        header("Location: adinistrativo.php");
    }else{
        $valor_pesquisar = $_GET['pesquisar'];
    }


    //Selecionar todos os curriculos da tabela, tentei buscar por mais uma tabela tipo o OR tabela empresa mas não rola.
    $result_curriculos = "SELECT * FROM curriculos WHERE nome LIKE '%$valor_pesquisar%' OR empresa LIKE '%$valor_pesquisar'";


    $resultado_curriculos = mysqli_query($conn, $result_curriculos);

    //Contar o total de curriculos 
    //Aqui gera um erro nessa linha - Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\wamp64\www\curriculo\adm\administrativo\pesquisar\pesquisar.php on line 84
    $total_curriculos = mysqli_num_rows($resultado_curriculos);

    //Seta a quantidade de curriculos por pagina
    $quantidade_pg = 6;

    //calcular o número de pagina necessárias para apresentar os curriculos
    $num_pagina = ceil($total_curriculos/$quantidade_pg);

    //Calcular o inicio da visualizacao
    $incio = ($quantidade_pg*$pagina)-$quantidade_pg;

    //Selecionar os curriculos a serem apresentado na página - aqui também da o erro Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\wamp64\www\curriculo\adm\administrativo\pesquisar\pesquisar.php on line 98
    $result_curriculos = "SELECT * FROM curriculos WHERE nome LIKE '%$valor_pesquisar%' OR empresa LIKE '%$valor_pesquisar' limit $incio, $quantidade_pg";
    $resultado_curriculos = mysqli_query($conn, $result_curriculos);
    $total_curriculos = mysqli_num_rows($resultado_curriculos);
    ?>

            <div class="container theme-showcase" role="main">
                <div class="page-header">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-12">
                        <h1>Curriculos</h1>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                        <!-- INICIO PESQUISA -->
                    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12" style="padding:0px;">
                    <form class="form-inline" method="GET" style="padding:20px 0px 20px 0px" action="pesquisar.php">
                        <div class="form-group" style="width:100%;">
                            <div class="form-group" style="width: 205px;">
                                <label class="col-sm-12 control-label">Nome do candidato</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-10">
                                <input type="text" name="pesquisar" class="form-control" style="width:200px;" id="exampleInputName2" placeholder="Nome do candidato...">
                                </div></div>

            <?php if(!empty($row_curriculos['empresa_id'])){
                $empresa_id = $row_curriculos['empresa_id']; 
            }?>
            <div class="form-group" style="width:205px;">
                <label class="col-sm-12 control-label">Empresa</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <select class="form-control" name="select_empresa">
                        <option value="">Selecione</option>
                        <?php
                        $result_empresa = "SELECT * FROM empresa";
                        $result_empresa = mysqli_query($conn, $result_empresa);
                        while($row_empresa = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_empresa)){ ?> 
                            <option value="<?php echo $row_empresa['id']; ?>"<?php
                            if(!empty($_SESSION['value_select_empresa'])){
                                if($_SESSION['value_select_empresa'] == $row_empresa['id']){
                                    echo 'selected';
                                    unset($_SESSION['value_select_empresa']);
                                }
                            }
                            if(!empty($row_curriculos['empresa_id'])){
                                if($empresa_id == $row_empresa['id']){
                                    echo 'selected';
                                }
                            }
                            ?> >                        
                            <?php echo $row_empresa['empresa']; ?></option>
                        <?php } ?>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>  
            <?php if(!empty($row_curriculos['area_id'])){
                $area_id = $row_curriculos['area_id']; 
            }?>
            <div class="form-group" style="width:145px;">
                <label class="col-sm-12 control-label">Área de atuação</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <select class="form-control" name="select_area">
                        <option value="">Selecione</option>
                        <?php
                        $result_area = "SELECT * FROM area";
                        $result_area = mysqli_query($conn, $result_area);
                        while($row_area = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_area)){ ?> 
                            <option value="<?php echo $row_area['id']; ?>"<?php
                            if(!empty($_SESSION['value_select_area'])){
                                if($_SESSION['value_select_area'] == $row_area['id']){
                                    echo 'selected';
                                    unset($_SESSION['value_select_area']);
                                }
                            }
                            if(!empty($row_curriculos['area_id'])){
                                if($area_id == $row_area['id']){
                                    echo 'selected';
                                }
                            }
                            ?> >                        
                            <?php echo $row_area['area']; ?></option>
                        <?php } ?>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>  
           <?php if(!empty($row_curriculos['cargo_id'])){
                $cargo_id = $row_curriculos['cargo_id']; 
            }?>
            <div class="form-group" style="width:145px;">
                <label class="col-sm-12 control-label">Cargo</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <select class="form-control" name="select_cargo">
                        <option value="">Selecione</option>
                        <?php
                        $result_cargo = "SELECT * FROM cargo";
                        $result_cargo = mysqli_query($conn, $result_cargo);
                        while($row_cargo = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_cargo)){ ?> 
                            <option value="<?php echo $row_cargo['id']; ?>"<?php
                            if(!empty($_SESSION['value_select_cargo'])){
                                if($_SESSION['value_select_cargo'] == $row_cargo['id']){
                                    echo 'selected';
                                    unset($_SESSION['value_select_cargo']);
                                }
                            }
                            if(!empty($row_curriculos['cargo_id'])){
                                if($cargo_id == $row_cargo['id']){
                                    echo 'selected';
                                }
                            }
                            ?> >                        
                            <?php echo $row_cargo['cargo']; ?></option>
                        <?php } ?>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>  
            <?php if(!empty($row_curriculos['situacao_id'])){
                $situacao_id = $row_curriculos['situacao_id']; 
            }?>
            <div class="form-group" style="width:145px;">
                <label class="col-sm-12 control-label">Sit. do curriculo</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <select class="form-control" name="select_situacao_curriculo">
                        <option value="">Selecione</option>
                        <?php
                        $result_situacao = "SELECT * FROM situacao_curriculo";
                        $result_situacao = mysqli_query($conn, $result_situacao);

                        while($row_situacao_curriculo = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_situacao)){ ?> 

                            <option value="<?php echo $row_situacao_curriculo['id']; ?>"
                            <?php
                            if(!empty($_SESSION['value_select_situacao_curriculo'])){
                                if($_SESSION['value_select_situacao_curriculo'] == $row_situacao['id']){
                                    echo 'selected';
                                    unset($_SESSION['value_select_situacao_curriculo']);
                                }
                            }
                            if(!empty($row_curriculos['situacao_id'])){
                                if($situacao_id == $row_situacao_curriculo['id']){
                                    echo 'selected';
                                }
                            }
                            ?> >                        
                            <?php echo $row_situacao_curriculo['nome']; ?></option>
                        <?php } ?>
                    </select> 
                </div>
            </div>  


                                    <button type="submit" style=" margin-left: 20px; margin-top: 19px;" class="btn btn-primary">Pesquisar</button>

                                </div>

                            </form>
                        </div>

                        <!-- FIM DA PESQUISA -->
                        <!-- FIM DA PESQUISA -->
                </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <table class="table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th class="text-center">ID</th>
                            <th class="text-center">Data de cadastro</th>
                            <th class="text-center">Nome</th>
                            <th class="text-center">E-mail</th>
                            <th class="text-center">Vaga de interesse</th>
                            <th class="text-center">Empresa</th>
                            <th class="text-center">Área de atuação</th>
                            <th class="text-center">Cargo</th>
                            <th class="text-center">Telefone</th>
                            <th class="text-center">Obs. do candidato</th>
                            <th class="text-center">Situação Curriculo</th>
                            <th class="text-center">Observação do R.H.</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
<!-- aqui gera outro erro Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\wamp64\www\curriculo\adm\administrativo\pesquisar\pesquisar.php on line 274 -->
                        <?php while($row_curriculos = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado_curriculos)){?>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="text-center"><?php echo $row_curriculos["id"]; ?></td>
                                <td class="text-center"><?php echo date('d/m/Y H:i:s',strtotime($row_curriculos["created"])); ?></td>
                                <td class="text-center"><?php echo $row_curriculos["nome"]; ?></td>
                                <td class="text-center"><?php echo $row_curriculos["email"]; ?></td>
                                <td class="text-center"><?php echo $row_curriculos["vaga"]; ?></td>
                                <td class="text-center"><?php 
                $situacao_atual = $row_curriculos['empresa_id'];
                $result_empresa = "SELECT * FROM empresa WHERE id = '$situacao_atual'";
                $result_empresa = mysqli_query($conn, $result_empresa);
                $row_empresa = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_empresa);
                echo $row_empresa['empresa']; ?>                                                            
                                </td>
                                <td class="text-center"><?php 
                $situacao_atual = $row_curriculos['area_id'];
                $result_area = "SELECT * FROM area WHERE id = '$situacao_atual'";
                $result_area = mysqli_query($conn, $result_area);
                $row_area = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_area);
                echo $row_area['area']; ?>  
                            </td>
                                <td class="text-center"><?php
                $situacao_atual = $row_curriculos['cargo_id'];
                $result_cargo = "SELECT * FROM cargo WHERE id = '$situacao_atual'";
                $result_cargo = mysqli_query($conn, $result_cargo);
                $row_cargo = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_cargo);
                echo $row_cargo['cargo']; ?>
                                </td>   
                                <td class="text-center"><?php echo $row_curriculos["telefone"]; ?></td>
                                <td class="text-center"><?php echo $row_curriculos["mensagem"]; ?></td>
                                <td class="text-center"><?php 
                $situacao_atual = $row_curriculos['situacao_id'];
                $result_situacao = "SELECT * FROM situacao_curriculo WHERE id = '$situacao_atual'";
                $result_situacao = mysqli_query($conn, $result_situacao);
                $row_situacao_curriculo = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_situacao);
                echo $row_situacao_curriculo['nome']; ?></td>
                                <td class="text-center"><?php echo $row_curriculos["mensagem_rh"]; ?></td>


                              <td class="text-center">
                                    <a href="administrativo.php?link=17&id=<?php echo $row_curriculos["id"]; ?>">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary">
                                            Visualizar
                                        </button>
                                    </a>
                                    <a href="administrativo.php?link=18&id=<?php echo $row_curriculos["id"]; ?>">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-warning">
                                            Editar
                                        </button>
                                    </a>
                                    <a href="administrativo/processa/adm_apagar_curriculo.php?id=<?php echo $row_curriculos["id"]; ?>">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger">
                                            Apagar
                                        </button>
                                    </a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        <?php } ?>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
                <?php
                    //Verificar a pagina anterior e posterior
                    $pagina_anterior = $pagina - 1;
                    $pagina_posterior = $pagina + 1;
                ?>
                <nav class="text-center">
                    <ul class="pagination">
                        <li>
                            <?php
                            if($pagina_anterior != 0){ ?>
                                <a href="pesquisar.php?pagina=<?php echo $pagina_anterior; ?>&pesquisar=<?php echo $valor_pesquisar; ?>" aria-label="Previous">
                                    <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
                                </a>
                            <?php }else{ ?>
                                <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
                        <?php }  ?>
                        </li>
                        <?php 
                        //Apresentar a paginacao
                        for($i = 1; $i < $num_pagina + 1; $i++){ ?>
                            <li><a href="pesquisar.php?pagina=<?php echo $i; ?>&pesquisar=<?php echo $valor_pesquisar; ?>"><?php echo $i; ?></a></li>
                        <?php } ?>
                        <li>
                            <?php
                            if($pagina_posterior <= $num_pagina){ ?>
                                <a href="pesquisar.php?pagina=<?php echo $pagina_posterior; ?>&pesquisar=<?php echo $valor_pesquisar; ?>" aria-label="Previous">
                                    <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
                                </a>
                            <?php }else{ ?>
                                <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
                        <?php }  ?>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
            <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
            ================================================== -->
            <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
            <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="../../assets/js/vendor/jquery.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
            <script src="../../js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
            <script src="../../js/docs.min.js"></script>
            <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
            <script src="../../js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Se eu utilizo o campo "nome" onde ele faz a pesquisa até vai, funciona, mas removendo o OR empresa LIKE '%$valor_pesquisa' - funciona correto somente pelo nome.

```
$result_curriculos = "SELECT * FROM curriculos WHERE nome LIKE '%$valor_pesquisar%' limit $incio, $quantidade_pg";
```

O que eu preciso é que se o usuario realize um filtro, por empresa ou cargo ou area ele filtre  resultado,

Para isso eu tenho as tabelas assim:

tabela curriculos
Colunas id | nome | E-mail | Telefone | area_id | cargo_id | empresa_id | situacao_id

tabela area
colunas id | area

tabela cargo
colunas id | cargo

Tabela empresa
colunas id | empresa

tabela situacao_curriculo
colunas id | nome

---

Bom acho que mostrei tudo que estou fazendo

E ainda deixo uma imagem para ilustrar como esta sendo feito.

Espero que alguém possa me ajudar, pois estou a uns dias nisso para finalizar um projetinho.

Obrigado

Segue imagem
https://screenshot.net/pt/0my0qsg

EDITADO ------------------------------

Fiz o que o amigo Jeferson sugeriu, mas não rolou.

Quando coloco 
**"SELECT * FROM curriculos as c, empresa as emp WHERE c.nome LIKE '%".$valor_pesquisar."%' OR emp.empresa LIKE '%".$valor_pesquisar."%'";**

Talvez a sintaxe esteja errada, vou melhorar o raciocínio para ver se os amigos ajudam.
Na tabela curriculos eu tenho a coluna empresa_id, nela busca somente o ID da empresa referente a tabela empresa exemplo empresa_id=3

Na tabela empresa tem a coluna ID | empresa - exemplo id=3 | empresa=SULMINAS

Então nessa tabela EMPRESA tenho assim:
ID=1 | empresa=NORTEMINAS
ID=2 | empresa=LESTEMINAS
ID=3 | empresa=SULMINAS

Na tabela CURRICULOS tenho assim:
ID=1 | NOME=FULANO | email=fulano@fulano.com.br | area_id=1 | empresa_id=3

Então na pesquisa tenho um select option que puxa a tabela curriculos e quando informa a coluna empresa_id - puxa o ID da tabela empresa, informando o nome da empresa

```
<select class="form-control" name="select_empresa">
                    <option value="">Selecione</option>
                    <?php
                    $result_empresa = "SELECT * FROM empresa";
                    $result_empresa = mysqli_query($conn, $result_empresa);
                    while($row_empresa = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_empresa)){ ?> 
                        <option value="<?php echo $row_empresa['id']; ?>"<?php
                        if(!empty($_SESSION['value_select_empresa'])){
                            if($_SESSION['value_select_empresa'] == $row_empresa['id']){
                                echo 'selected';
                                unset($_SESSION['value_select_empresa']);
                            }
                        }
                        if(!empty($row_curriculos['empresa_id'])){
                            if($empresa_id == $row_empresa['id']){
                                echo 'selected';
                            }
                        }
                        ?> >                        
                        <?php echo $row_empresa['empresa']; ?></option>
                    <?php } ?>
                </select>
```

Então ao selecionar no select option a empresa=SULMINAS e clicar no botão pesquisar ele deve exibir somente o resultado com o ID | nome | email | area | empresa

Quando clicar no pesquisar exibir somente a lista de usuário que selecionou a empresa no select do cadastro.
[image: https://screenshot.net/pt/p0krmuy]

Eu tenho essas duas Query

```
//As que selecionam todos os curriculos da tabela
$result_curriculos = "SELECT * FROM curriculos WHERE nome LIKE '%$valor_pesquisar%'";
//se ela é usada assim e eu uso o campo nome TEXT (digitando qualquer letra, a pesquisa filtra o nome).
```

e tenho essas query's para exibir o resultado da pesquisa

```
$result_curriculos = "SELECT * FROM curriculos WHERE nome LIKE '%$valor_pesquisar%' limit $incio, $quantidade_pg";
$resultado_curriculos = mysqli_query($conn, $result_curriculos);
$total_curriculos = mysqli_num_rows($resultado_curriculos);
```

- Preciso entender da sintaxe que puxe o valor do select option da tabela CURRICULOS, coluna EMPRESA - puxando o ID e o resultado seja somente daquele ID.
- E preciso entender a sintaxe que exiba o resultado da pesquisa.
- Gostaria que a pesquisa trabalhe-se independente de como realiza a seleção no Select Option - tipo se ele utilizar somente a empresa para exibir o resultado, ou a combinação empresa e cargo. tipo quero resultados da empresa SULMINAS no cargo de ANALISTA, ou somente exibir o resultado da EMPRESA ou somente do CARGO.

Acho que agora a explicação está bem mais completo.

Ajudaria muito de uma solução
Agradeço a atenção de todos.

Comment: no caso o like seria por nome ou id da empresa?

Comment: pelo exposto acima a coluna nome está na tabela curriculo e a coluna empresa na tabela empresa, portanto sua query não está correta.

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo realmente o nome da empresa e o nome do candidato estão em tabelas diferentes. Alterei a Query na resposta, creio que agora resolva o problema.

Comment: hehehe, se mysqli fosse mais esperto, nesses casos, ele deveria procurar  o campo faltante nessa tabela em outras tabelas e sugerir o select no warning

Comment: Não somos um fórum, não coloque a **resposta** no corpo da **pergunta** e não é necessário o titulo RESOLVIDO e muito menos o uso desnecessário de CapsLock, simplesmente marque a resposta que acha correta, veja o tour e entenda o site primeiro http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 0):

Considerando que você está buscando pelo **Nome do Candidato** ou **Nome da Empresa**, acredito que seja um pequeno erro de sintaxe na sua Query. Além de não estar fazendo a junção das tabelas já que nome do candidato está em uma tabela diferente de empresa. Tente:

```
 "SELECT * FROM curriculos as c, empresa as emp 
  WHERE c.nome LIKE '%".$valor_pesquisar."%' OR emp.empresa LIKE '%".$valor_pesquisar."%'";
```

Comment: testei a query igual a dele - WHERE CustomerName LIKE '%Drachenblut Delikatessend%' OR ContactName LIKE '%Guillermo Fernández';  - em https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_like e funciona

Comment: Sim, ela funciona.. o problema é a sintaxe como o amigo Jeferson Leonardo comentou.